# How to show HTML code using angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, xml

In one of my application I am using angularjs for internalization. I am having different json files from which i am getting texts as per the market. I am importing them into XML. Then in in jsp i am importing those XML to view.

The problem is if i am giving some HTML tag inside XML like

```
&lt;sup&gt;1&lt;/sup&gt;
```

its working, but the same thing is not working if it passed from JSON. Please help.. thanks in advance

```
json is
"pwpDetail": "&lt;sup&gt;1&lt;/sup&gt;

Controller -  
$http.get(languageFilePath2).success(function(data){
     $scope.datav=data;
 });
```

XML -

```
<description>{{datav.pwpDetail}}</description>
```

The print the HTML code as string not as a super script

Answer (score 0):

<sup>1</sup> You just [need to Decode](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/htmlencode/Decode.aspx) the output to get back the original HTML.

[Use javascript unescape function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unescape.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you would want this:

For Angular 1.3, use ng-bind-html in the HTML:

```
<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="datav.pwpDetail"></div>
```

And in the controller:

```
function htmlDecode(input){
  var e = document.createElement('div');
  e.innerHTML = input;
  return e.childNodes.length === 0 ? "" : e.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}  

$http.get(languageFilePath2).success(function(data){
     data.pwpDetail = htmlDecode(data.pwpDetail);
     $scope.datav=data;
 });
```

Comment: @ Angulo, edited my question for better understanding, can you please look into it when let me know how i can approach it

Comment: I have many json values to be called in similar fashion... so how to use this approach.

Comment: mmm maybe you can create an angular filter that decodes the html encode string.